# SQL Server Analysis Service 2008 R2 LONG CONTINUOUS Data Type

Tags: c#, sql-server, types, ssas

I've been seraching for the data type of `LONG CONTINUOUS` in SQL Server Analysis Services 2008 R2. Can anyone point me to the documentation?

I found a [description of the data types](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174796.aspx), but it said nothing on the actual data.

What is the C# equivalent?

I was using `AdomdDataReader.GetInt32()`, but I increased the predictions and now a few records came back as the data was either "too small" or "too large".

Comment: Perhaps edit your question to include a code snippet & long values demonstrating the errors for 'too small/large'? Also, what are the exact error messages and source (SQL Server or .NET)?

Comment: That's the problem, I don't know what the value is. If I knew the value, then I could easily figure out which data type it could be. Which doesn't help me at all. And the error is what I quoted about Int32 is either too small or too big.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I figured it out. It is an Int64 so retrieving it as AdomdDataReader.GetInt32() or AdomdDataReader.GetInt64() will work. Obviously a long is a Int64, that should've been my answer from the start. Problem is in the past I've had other data types and had had problems with not putting the specific data type, but I guess in this case I was putting it as a lower data type (int32 intsead of int64) and it allowed me to do that. In the past I had tried getting a int16 by calling it int32 and that gave me problems. So yes problem resolved. Now my next issues is why the analysis service generating such a huge number, but guess that's not for this question heh.